# Has Coreplot released a new version for iOS 9?

Tags: core-plot, ios9

Just "upgraded" xcode 7 and iOS 9 and now my app blows up with all kinds of coreplot and link errors. I see lots of info on coreplot/ios9 but nothing that helps me.

Comment: Why not go to the CorePlot project page and look.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did and there's nothing there. That's why I checked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot version 2.0 should be out soon. There's a problem with text on OS X El Capitan (see [issue 210](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/210)) that needs to be fixed before it is released.

In the mean time, you can use the code on the `release-2.0` or `xcode-7` branch. Release 1.6 should also continue to work.

Comment: Hi, any estimate on core plot 2.0? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Core Plot release 2.0 is out. You can find all of the Core Plot releases on [Github](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases).